# Single Image Inference in Tensorflow not working

Tags: python, tensorflow, inference

I've a weird problem with inference on a trained tensorflow model.

First the model:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
sess = tf.Session()

def model(x_in,pkeep):

epsilon = 1e-3
# 1. 6x6 Conv2D (28,28,1) -> (28,28,6) with ReLU
# 2. 5x5 Conv2D (28,28,6) -> (14,14,12) with ReLU
# 3. 4x4 Conv2D (14,14,12) -> (7,7,24) with ReLU
# 4. 4x4 Conv2D     # 4. Flatten Layer (7,7,24) -> (1176,1)
# 5. FC Layer (1176,1) -> (200,1) with ReLU
# 6. Dropout
# 7. FC Layer (200,1) -> (10,1)

K = 6  # first convolutional layer output depth
L = 12  # second convolutional layer output depth
M = 24  # third convolutional layer
N = 48 # fourth convolutional layer
O = 96 # five convolutional layer

S = 200 # fully connected layer
numClasses = 4

with tf.name_scope("conv1"):
    #wc1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([6, 6, 1, K], stddev=0.1), name="wc1")
    wc1 = tf.get_variable(shape=[6, 6, 1, K],initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), name="wc1")
    bc1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[K]), name="bc1")
    conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(x_in, wc1, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME")
    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv1 + bc1)
    tf.summary.histogram("weights_conv_1", wc1)
    tf.summary.histogram("biases_conv_1", bc1)
    tf.summary.histogram("activations", conv1)     
# Output: 28x28xK

with tf.name_scope("conv2"):
    #wc2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, K, L], stddev=0.1), name="wc2")
    wc2 = tf.get_variable(shape=[5, 5, K, L],initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), name="wc2")
    bc2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[L]), name="bc2")
    conv2 = tf.nn.conv2d(conv1, wc2, strides=[1, 1, 2, 1], padding="SAME")
    conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2 + bc2)
    tf.summary.histogram("weights_conv_2", wc2)
    tf.summary.histogram("biases_conv_2", bc2)
    tf.summary.histogram("activations", conv2)
# Output: 14x14xL

with tf.name_scope("conv3"):
    #wc3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([4, 4, L, M], stddev=0.1), name="wc3")
    wc3 = tf.get_variable(shape=[4, 4, L, M],initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(),name="wc3")
    bc3 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[M]), name="bc3")
    conv3 = tf.nn.conv2d(conv2, wc3, strides=[1, 1, 2, 1], padding="SAME")
    conv3 = tf.nn.relu(conv3 + bc3)
    tf.summary.histogram("weights_conv_3", wc3)
    tf.summary.histogram("biases_conv_3", bc3)
    tf.summary.histogram("activations", conv3)

with tf.name_scope("conv4"): 
    #wc4 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([4, 4, M, N], stddev=0.1), name="wc4")
    wc4 = tf.get_variable(shape=[4, 4, M, N],initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), name="wc4")
    bc4 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[N]), name="bc4")
    conv4 = tf.nn.conv2d(conv3, wc4, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME")
    conv4 = tf.nn.relu(conv4 + bc4)
    tf.summary.histogram("weights_conv_4", wc4)
    tf.summary.histogram("biases_conv_4", bc4)
    tf.summary.histogram("activations", conv4)

with tf.name_scope("conv5"):
    #wc5 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, N, O], stddev=0.1), name="wc5")
    wc5 = tf.get_variable(shape=[3, 3, N, O],initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), name="wc5")
    bc5 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[O]), name="bc5")
    conv5 = tf.nn.conv2d(conv4, wc5, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME")
    conv5 = tf.nn.relu(conv5 + bc5)
    tf.summary.histogram("weights_conv_5", wc5)
    tf.summary.histogram("biases_conv_5", bc5)
    tf.summary.histogram("activations", conv5)

# Output: 7x7xM
flattened = tf.reshape(conv5, [-1, 8 * 31 * O]) #7 * 7 * M

with tf.name_scope("fc1"):
    #wf1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([8 * 31 * O, S], stddev=0.1), name="wf1")
    wf1 = tf.get_variable(shape=[8 * 31 * O, S],initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), name="wf1")
    bf1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[S]), name="bf1")
    fc1 = tf.matmul(flattened, wf1) + bf1

    batch_mean2, batch_var2 = tf.nn.moments(fc1,[0])
    scale1 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([S]))
    beta1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([S]))
    BN2 = tf.nn.batch_normalization(fc1,batch_mean2,batch_var2,beta1,scale1,epsilon)

    relu = tf.nn.relu(BN2)
    dropout = tf.nn.dropout(relu,pkeep,name="dropout")
    tf.summary.histogram("weights_fc_1", wf1)
    tf.summary.histogram("biases_conv_1", bf1)
    tf.summary.histogram("activations", fc1)

with tf.name_scope("fc2"):
    #wf2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([S, numClasses], stddev=0.1), name="wf2")
    wf2 = tf.get_variable(shape=[S, numClasses],initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), name="wf2")
    bf2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[numClasses]), name="bf2")
    logits = tf.matmul(dropout, wf2) + bf2
    tf.summary.histogram("weights_fc_2", wf2)
    tf.summary.histogram("biases_conv_2", bf2)
    tf.summary.histogram("activations", logits)


return logits


def compute_cost(logits,labels):
    with tf.name_scope("loss"):
        xent = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=labels), name="xent")
        tf.summary.scalar("loss", xent)
    return xent

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 968], name="x")
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 8, 121, 1])

y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 4], name="y")
pkeep = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,name="pkeep")
step = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,name="step")
learning_rate = 0.0003
logits = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,name="logits")
logits = model(x_image,pkeep)
cost = compute_cost(logits,y)

with tf.name_scope("train"):
    lr = learning_rate +  tf.train.exponential_decay(0.003, step, 2000, 1/math.e)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr).minimize(cost)

with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32),name="accuracyV")
    tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy)
    tf.add_to_collection("accuracy", accuracy)
```

I tried now to do a inference test with a single example from the test set ( during training I got around 95% accuracy). This is my code:

```
n = 0
with tf.Session() as sess:
    new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('C:\\...'))
    predictions =sess.run(logits,feed_dict={x: x_test[n,:][np.newaxis],pkeep: 1.0})
    pred_max = np.argmax(predictions, 1)
    print(pred_max )  
    print(y_test[n])
```

As result I got alway (independent to the y_test label) the same prediction - class 0 with nearly the same logits (0.249904 -0.0239285  -0.0824487  0.0551006). The weird part is now that in the case I do the inference test on more than one image at the same time. I get completely other values and also right predictions:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('C:\\...'))
    predictions =sess.run(logits,feed_dict={x: x_test[0:10,:],pkeep: 1.0})
    pred_max = np.argmax(predictions, 1)
    print(pred_max)
    print(y_test[0:10])
```

The value of the same logits (index = 0) for example is now -6.45629    3.54225 3.75237 -7.38902. This makes in my interpretation much more sense. Also results to the correct class.

Has someone an explanation for this strange behaviour?

Comment: Got to do with `batch normalization`, their calls differ when training vs inference. From the code it looks like you are not doing it right.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply!

I changed the batch normalization layer to
'hidden_layer_bn = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(fc1,is_training=is_training)' and give the particular boolean operator for training / inference. Also I added the update_ops part.
'update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
    with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
        optimizer =[...]'

But sadly I got still the same issue - it predicts always the same class. Only with the difference of more sensing values ([-23.43   17.11  14.47 -65.05 ])